# Can't click button on tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I am new to tkinter and I am having trouble with buttons on the python GUI. I create the buttons and the function behind it but I am unable to click the button. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? The UI comes up and I can see the button I just can't click it.

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import filedialog, Text

import os


#main
root = tk.Tk()

def addApp():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialir= "/", title= "Select File",
                                          filetypes = (("executables", "*.exe"),
                                                        ("all files", "*.*")))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#33F9FF")

canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1)

openFile = tk.Button(root, text = "Open File", padx = 10, pady = 5, fg="black",
                     bg="#33F9FF", command="addApp")

openFile.pack()

runApps = tk.Button(root, text = "Run Apps", padx = 10, pady = 5, fg="black",
                    bg="#33F9FF")

runApps.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command=addApp`

Comment: that threw a bunch of errors. Still doesn't allow me to actually click the button

Comment: Not quite sure that this errors somehow related to edit from previous comment.

Comment: The `command` option requires a callable function, not a string.

Comment: Gotchu ya, I just realized that. I've made the change now just running into some exceptions from Tkinter callback. Thank you!

Comment: Regardless of the command option, I should still be able to click the button and have some sort of interaction correct? Like a change of color to show that I've interacted with the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also one more mistake:

```py
def addApp():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir= '/', title= "Select File",
                                          filetypes = (("executables", "*.exe"),
                                                        ("all files", "*.*")))
```

Comment: That was it right there. Thank you guys! I really gotta get my eyes checked haha

Answer (score 5):

Very, small mistake. You added command argument as a string and not a function

```
openFile = tk.Button(root, text = "Open File", padx = 10, pady = 5, fg="black",
                     bg="#33F9FF", command=addApp)
```

EDIT: 
there is a small typo at `initialdir` argument in openfiledialogbox

```
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir= "/", title= "Select File",
                                          filetypes = (("executables", "*.exe"),
                                                        ("all files", "*.*")))
```