# Bracket not closed error python in VS Code

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a program in Python, but it gives me an error that the brackets are not closed.

```
openFile = tk.Button( root, text="Open File", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="black", command=addApp)
```

Comment: add a comma after `pady=5`

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the error msg.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161262/cant-click-button-on-tkinter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't click button on tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161262/cant-click-button-on-tkinter)

Answer (score 2):

There is a comma missing after `pady=5`.

Answer (score 0):

Ahem, the REAL problem here is .. you've put a space at the start bracket, none at the end! I can see that the COMMAS here are completely fine, right where they should be. Opposite for the brackets though. I've had this problem in my case before!

Comment: add it not as an answer but a comment

Answer (score -1):

I found that its usually just the user missing a comma somewhere.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).